# Mean imputation method: graph representation?

Tags: r, mean, missing-data, imputation

Good morning,
I'm dealing with graphic representation of missing data imputeted via mean imputation method. This is the dataset I'm working on:

```
> data2
    age   fev  ht sex smoke
1     9 1.708 145   1     1
2     8 1.724 171   1     1
3     7 1.720 138   1     1
4     9 1.558 135   2     1
5     9 1.895 145   2     1
6     8 2.336 155   1     1
7     6 1.919 147   1     1
8     6 1.415 142   1     1
9     8 1.987 149   1     1
10    9 1.942 152   1     1
11    6 1.602 135   1     1
12    8 1.735 137   2     1
13    8 2.193 149   1     1
14    8 2.118 154   2     1
15    8 2.258 147   2     1
16    7 1.932 135   2     1
17    5 1.472 127   2     1
18    6 1.878  NA   1     1
19    9 2.352 150   2     1
20    9 2.604 156   2     1
21    5 1.400 124   1     1
22    5 1.256 133   1     1
23    4 0.839 122   1     1
24    7 2.578 159   2     1
25    9 2.988 165   1     1
26    3 1.404 131   2     1
27    9 2.348 152   2     1
28    5 1.755 132   2     1
29    8 2.980 152   1     1
30    9 2.100 152   1     1
31    5 1.282 124   1     1
32    9 3.000 166   2     1
33    8 2.673 152   1     1
34    7 2.093 146   1     1
35    5 1.612 132   1     1
36    8 2.175 150   1     1
37    9 2.725 150   2     1
38    8 2.071 140   2     1
39    8 1.547 145   2     1
40    8 2.004 145   2     1
41    9 3.135 152   1     1
42    8 2.420 150   2     1
43    5 1.776 130   2     1
44    8 1.931 145   1     1
45    5 1.343 127   1     1
46    9 2.076 145   1     1
47    7 1.624 137   2     1
48    8 1.344 133   1     1
49    6 1.650 140   2     1
50    8 2.732 154   2     1
51    5 2.017 138   2     1
52    9 2.797 156   1     1
53    9    NA 157   2     1
54    8 1.703 138   2     1
55    6 1.634 137   2     1
56    9 2.570 145   2     1
57    9 3.016 159   1     1
58    7 2.419 152   1     1
59    4 1.569 127   1     1
60    8 1.698 146   1     1
61    8 2.123 152   2     1
62    8 2.481 152   1     1
63    6 1.481 130   1     1
64    4 1.577 124   1     1
65    8 1.940 150   2     1
66    6 1.747 146   2     1
67    9 2.069 147   2     1
68    7 1.631 141   1     1
69    5 1.536 132   1     1
70    9 2.560 154   1     1
71    8 1.962 145   2     1
72    8 2.531 147   1     1
73    9 2.715 152   2     1
74    9 2.457 150   2     1
75    9 2.090 151   2     1
76    7 1.789 142   2     1
77    5 1.858 135   2     1
78    5 1.452 130   2     1
79    9    NA 175   2     1
80    6 1.719 135   1     1
81    7 2.111 145   1     1
82    6 1.695 135   1     1
83    8 2.211 160   2     1
84    8 1.794 138   2     1
85    7 1.917 147   1     1
86    8 2.144  NA   1     1
87    7 1.253 132   2     1
88    9 2.659 156   2     1
89    5 1.580 133   2     1
90    9 2.126 157   2     1
91    9 3.029 156   1     1
92    9 2.964 164   2     1
93    7 1.611  NA   2     1
94    8 2.215 152   1     1
95    8 2.388 152   1     1
96    9 2.196 155   2     1
97    9 1.751 147   2     1
98    9 2.165 156   2     1
99    7 1.682 140   2     1
100   8 1.523 140   2     1
101   8 1.292 132   1     1
102   7 1.649 137   2     1
103   9 2.588 160   2     1
104   4 0.796 119   2     1
105   9 2.574 154   1     1
106   6 1.979 142   2     1
107   8 2.354 149   2     1
108   6 1.718 140   2     1
109   7 1.742 149   1     1
110   7 1.603 130   1     1
111   8 2.639 151   1     1
112   7 1.829 137   1     1
113   7 2.084 147   2     1
114   7 2.220 147   2     1
115   7 1.473 133   1     1
116   8 2.341 154   1     1
117   7 1.698 138   1     1
118   5 1.196 118   1     1
119   8 1.872 144   1     1
120   7 2.219 140   2     1
121   9 2.420 145   2     1
122   7 1.827 138   1     1
123   7 1.461 137   1     1
124   6 1.338  NA   2     1
125   8 2.090 145   2     1
126   8 1.697 150   1     1
127   8 1.562 140   2     1
128   9 2.040 141   1     1
129   7 1.609 131   1     1
130   8 2.458 155   1     1
131   9 2.650 161   2     1
132   8 1.429 146   2     1
133   8 1.675 135   2     1
134   9 1.947 144   1     1
135   8 2.069 137   2     1
136   6 1.572 132   2     1
137   6 1.348 135   2     1
138   8 2.288 156   1     1
139   9 1.773 149   2     1
140   5 0.791 132   1     1
141   7 1.905 147   2     1
142   9 2.463 155   1     1
143   6 1.431 130   2     1
144   9 2.631 157   1     1
145   9 3.114 164   2     1
146   9 2.135 149   2     1
147   6 1.527 133   2     1
148   8 2.293 147   1     1
149   9 3.042 168   1     1
150   8 2.927 161   2     1
151   8 2.665 163   1     1
152   9 2.301 149   2     1
153   9 2.460 163   2     1
154   9 2.592 154   1     1
155   7 1.750 140   1     1
156   8 1.759 135   2     1
157   6 1.536 122   2     1
158   9 2.259 149   1     1
159   9 2.048 164   1     1
160   9 2.571 154   2     1
161   7 2.046 142   2     1
162   8 1.780 149   1     1
163   5 1.552 137   1     1
164   8 1.953 147   1     1
165   9 2.893 164   2     1
166   6 1.713 128   2     1
167   9 2.851 152   1     1
168   6 1.624 131   2     1
169   8 2.631 150   2     1
170   5 1.819 135   2     1
171   7 1.658 135   2     1
172   7 2.158 136   2     1
173   4 1.789 132   2     1
174   9 3.004 163   1     1
175   8 2.503 160   2     1
176   9 1.933 147   1     1
177   9 2.091 149   1     1
178   9 2.316  NA   1     1
179   5 1.704  NA   1     1
180   9 1.606 146   1     1
181   7 1.165 119   2     1
182   6 2.102 141   1     1
183   9 2.320 145   1     1
184   9 2.230 155   2     1
185   9 1.716 141   2     1
186   7 1.790 136   2     1
187   5 1.146 127   1     1
188   8 2.187 156   1     1
189   9 2.717 156   2     1
190   7 1.796 140   2     1
191   9 1.953 147   2     2
192   8 1.335 144   1     1
193   9 2.119 145   2     1
194   6 1.666 132   2     1
195   6 1.826 133   2     1
196   8 2.709 159   1     1
197   9 2.871 165   2     1
198   5 1.092 127   1     1
199   6 2.262 146   2     1
200   6 2.104 144   2     1
```

I've used the following code to return back the observed vs the imputed data scenario and the sided scatterplot of Y="fev" versus X="age".

```
1. FIRST GRAPH
library(lattice)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
breaks <- seq(-20, 200, 10)
nudge <- 1
lwd <- 1.5
x <- matrix(c(breaks-nudge, breaks+nudge), ncol=2, nrow = 46)
obs <- data2[,"fev"]
mis  <- imp$imp$fev[,1]
fobs <- c(hist(obs, breaks, plot=FALSE)$fev, 0)
fmis <- c(hist(mis, breaks, plot=FALSE)$fev, 0)
y <- matrix(c(fobs, fmis), ncol=2, nrow = 46)
matplot(x, y, type="s",
        col=c(mdc(4),mdc(5)), lwd=2, lty=1,
        xlim = c(0, 150), ylim = c(0,40), yaxs = "i",
        xlab="fev",
        ylab="Frequency")
box() 

2. SECOND GRAPH
tp <- xyplot(imp, fev ~ age, na.groups=ici(imp), 
             ylab="fev", xlab="age",
             cex = 0.75, lex=lwd, pch=19,
             ylim = c(-20, 180), xlim = c(0,350))
print(tp, newpage = FALSE, position = c(0.48,0.08,1,0.92))
```

Although the code works well, I'm not so as to its validity, as I am supposed to have back a graphic results like those I let attached here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTrhO.png), whereas I'm keeping on getting a sort of graphs like these [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YocLS.png)

What do you think about? Any clue as to making the right cade out?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the complete code. It isn't exactly clear what your `imp` data, which you are trying to plot looks like. The data you posted is named `data2`, but I don't really know at which point in your code this is used.

As for reasons, why your code might not not show anything, it seems the range for `fev` is about from 0 to 3. `age` is about from 1 to 10.

But axis limits in the first plot are:

```
xlim = c(0, 150), ylim = c(0,40)
```

In the second plot

```
ylim = c(-20, 180), xlim = c(0,350)
```

Which means, the actual data you want to plot is in quite a small area of the plot (as you can see).

You have to adjust your axis limits to the range of your data.